# My Xaml cs file cant find my xaml Textbox UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So i have a view of Restock posibilites and now im trying to make a TextBox where i can write input of how much i want to fill the stock with. But my Xaml.cs file dont wanna find the TextBox. Do i miss something?

My xmal code

```
<TextBlock Text="Restock" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind _merchandiseManager.merchlist}" Grid.Column="1">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Merchandise">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Width="200" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20"  Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Supplier}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Stock}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="AmountBox" FontSize="15" Text=""/>

                        <Button Name="Submit" Click="Submit_Click" FontSize="15" Width="50" Height="40" Content="Add"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

And where i want to find it
I bascily want to find the TextBox in the AddToStock Method

```
 public RestockOption()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
           // _merchandise = new Merchandise();
            _merchandiseManager = new MerchandiseManager();

          
        }

        public void AddToStock(int amount, string itemName)
        {
          
            

            foreach (var item in _merchandiseManager.merchlist)
            {
                if(item.Name == itemName)
                {
                    item.Stock += amount;
                }
            }

        }

        private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           AddToStock();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since this, I got help from a teacher, he said since the Listview is kinda like a loop, the program cant find the correct textbox since all the textboxes has the same name. I gotta use LINQ which i havent learned yet so i have no really simple answer to this questions